# Efficient Stopwatch

Tags: javascript, performance, processing-efficiency

Hi I'm programming a stopwatch utility in javascript and I have a question about efficiency and overhead. There are two ways I have considered making the stopwatch:

1.Store a start Date and constantly measure the number of milliseconds it has been since that date.

2.Create an integer and increment its value at a set interval.

I want to know which is most efficient. Also, I'm not sure if option #2 would be very accurate, if anyone has any input about this that would be awesome as well.

Comment: #1 is both more efficient AND #2 will not work, because you can't guarantee the time between 'ticks'.

Comment: `performance.now()` is available in modern browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, go with #1. If you want a clock that ticks each second (or minute or whatever) you should estimate the time to the next "tick" so that *setTimeout* is called a few ms after the right time, e.g. to run just after the next whole second:

```
var d = new Date();
var interval = 1020 - d.getMilliseconds();
setTimeout(fn, interval);
```

That way if execution for one call is delayed by the system being busy, the next one should still be called about 20ms after the next whole second.

Comment: This can still miss timeouts (e.g. computer goes to sleep); a delta inside the timeout is still required, depending upon what is required.

Comment: Of course anything in a browser is dependent on the browser executing the script. What do you mean by a "delta inside the timeout"?

Comment: The point about making sure the clock is updated at the right time is interesting. However, without this the clock will still display the right time even if it is behind on the display, won't it?

Comment: @Drew - it will display the right time *when it updates*, but it may show the wrong time (for a shorter or longer period, depending on the regularity of the update) before that. The idea is to have it update as regularly as possible — i.e. as close to the "tick" as possible — as even minor lag or jerkiness in regular updates will be apparent to the user and cause them to lose confidence in the timer.

Answer (score 3):

Option 2 will not be accurate, especially if you have a page with additional javascript for other purposes.  Go with the first approach.

Comment: However, with option #1 a *clock change* should be accounted for. That is, the expected change and the actual change should be compared (with an appropriate margin of error) -- and corrected if needed. Granted, it's a very edge-case.