# Javascript setTimeOut function is not matched the time with Timer of Windows application in .net?

Tags: c#, javascript, windows, settimeout

I am working one of windows application in C#.Net and one of web application. I used Timer control on windows application and using `SetTimeOut()` function in web application. But when I run both then after 1 or 2 minutes shown less seconds then windows application time.

Using Java script code like:

```
function TimerDisplay(hour, min, sec, id) 
{
      $("#" + id).html(hour.pad() + ":" + min.pad() + ":" + sec.pad());
    if (sec >= 59) {
        sec = 0;
        if (min >= 59) {
            min = 0;
            sec = 0;
            hour += 1;
        }
        else {
            min += 1;
            sec = 0;
        }
    } 
    else
        sec += 1;
    setTimeout(function () { TimerDisplay(hour, min, sec, id); }, 1000);  
}



Number.prototype.pad = function () {
    return (this < 10 ? '0' : '') + this;
}
```

Please give suggestion if anyone has idea.

Comment: How are you calculating `hour, min, sec`? Where's the rest of the code? Any c# code?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript's *setTimeout* doesn't run at an exact time, it's put on a queue to run after the interval has expired. If the CPU is busy, it may be run quite a bit after the interval.

If you want a more accurate interval, you need to run a function at more frequent intervals and try to estimate when the next call should be made at as close a time as possible to the required interval. See [Efficient Stopwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935920/efficient-stopwatch/6936028#6936028).

Comment: It may possible but when i decrease interval let say 850 it run bit faster. How can i calculate that after how muhc delay CPU executed this?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a single threaded application so set timeout may not be called at regular interval because CPU might be busy in doing some other type of tasks.

Comment: How can i get rid of this ? Can i calculate the interval when CPU does not execute SetTimeout ?